# Colored chapter titles with the quotchap package

Tags: sectioning, color, chapters, quotchap

I already changed the chapter numbers using

```
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{}
```

But there must be some way to change the chapter titles also. Someone knows how?

Comment: What is `quotchap`?

Comment: I've edited the title accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A short peak into `quotchap.sty` tells me to redefine `\sectfont` (which contains only `\relax` by default):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\colorlet{chaptergrey}{green}
\renewcommand*\sectfont{\color{blue}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test} % green number, blue text
\section{Test} % all black
\subsection{Test} % all black
\end{document}
```